# rows, cols, _ = frame.shape AttributeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘shape

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, tracking

Hello everyone i have error when i want to execute the following code a, anyone can help me in this

```
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    # frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.8, fy=0.8)
    rows, cols, _ = frame.shape
    keyboard[:] = (26, 26, 26)
    frames += 1
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `frame` variable is `None`. Ie.

```
_, frame = cap.read() # <- This fails for some reason.
```

You need to provide some more info on `cap` before we can help with it.

Comment: thanks for quick answe it was the problem thta i forget and give 1 for cap but i used the laptop camera so i chnaged to 0 and now it is working perfect :))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))